# Can i use one wp plugin inside other?

Tags: plugin-development

i want to scrape the data of a Blog, process it and the make recommendations for my website. however, i'm not getting proper API to get the data, but i got another plugin which scrapes the data. so may i use this data scraping plugin inside mine.
Responses awaited.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. If you want to scrape data from somebody else's website. You are not permitted to use this on your site (copyrights). If it is your own site you want scrape, you can easily create a small plugin that gives you the right api-end point data.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you certainly can. At bare minimum, just require the plugin's main file inside your plugin file. You'll just need to activate YOUR plugin, but you'll still have function from the included plugin.

`require_once '/otherplugin/main-file.php';`

If you want to make it more sophisticated, you could set up a composer.json file in your plugin, which could then be run to automatically download specific versions as a dependency.